# Error while taking backup in Postgresql (Could not read Block X of relation base/Y/Z)

Tags: postgresql

while taking a backup from my `PostgrSQL Database`

it showing that

```
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "gtab17" failed: PQgetResult() failed.

pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid page header in block 9576 of relation     base/17779/758869

pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.gtab17 (jrdetid, jrmid, acid, dr, cr, narr, ageamt) TO stdout;
```

i think my table `gtab17` is corrupt

tried

- `Vaccum Full` error on this table

> INFO:  vacuuming "public.gtab17" ; ERROR:  row is too big: size 3256104, maximum size 8160

- `Analyze` error

> INFO:  analyzing "public.gtab17" ;
>   ERROR:  invalid page header in block 9576 of relation base/17779/758869

```
Database : PostgreSQL 9.2
OS : Windows XP SP3 ; FILESYSTEM : NTFS
```

i have googled but dint get any solution to solve this

Comment: This seems to be a clone of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/65171/7788 by a different user. Huh? If you're the same person with different user account, please delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, so your data file is corrupted - a solution is relative difficult - the best way is recovery from some older backup. You can try to fix it with replacing broken data page by zeroes - but you lost some data, and without some deeper knowledgeable you can destroy more than now it is.

[REFER](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59948/trying-to-restore-a-corrupt-postgresql-database-with-corrupt-data-folder-able)